# An EF Core query on a SQL Server view is getting data is null error

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, nullreferenceexception

I have an EF Core query against a SQL Server view that throws a

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException

How do I determine what value is null?

When I use "Show Results" for the view, all the rows have valid data. My other queries against views work properly.

The query is:

```
List<View_ProductWithCategoryTags> prods = 
    _db.View_ProductWithCategoryTags
       .OrderBy(p => p.ProductName).ToList();
```

The view definition is:

```
[Keyless]
public partial class View_ProductWithCategoryTags
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; } = "";
    public string ImageURL { get; set; } = "";

    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductCost { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; } = "";
    public string SKU { get; set; } = "";
    public int StockQuantity { get; set; }

    public string Tags { get; set; } = "";
    public string Categories { get; set; } = "";
}
```

The view results are:

[image: View Data with no null values]

How can I determine what is causing the Null Value error?

Comment: Technically it is not a "SQL Server view" but one defined in code perhaps.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I have reviewed the "duplicate" post and attempted all its solutions. I am still getting the error. Since the referenced answer is over 2 years old, there may have been changes in EFCore that have changed how this works.

Comment: I should mention that in ssms, tags return as null (select top 1000 row) and in VS2022 Server Explorer, Show Results returns all columns with non-null data ????